# XDMP-UNDFUN: (err:XPST0017) Undefined function op:join-full-outer() in MarkLogic 10

Tags: marklogic

I am getting:

> XDMP-UNDFUN: (err:XPST0017) Undefined function op:join-full-outer()

error in MarkLogic Query Console, even after importing the right module.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code showing the import and invocation of the function? If you copy/paste the example from that function page https://docs.marklogic.com/op:join-full-outer, same error? Also, what version of MarkLogic server are you running?

Comment: Hi Mads Hansen, Sorry for late response, Issue is resolved after clearing my module database and redeploy the modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for full outer joins was released in 10.0-5.

Are you using that version or a later version?

Answer (score 1):

Issue got resolved after clearing the module database and redeploy it again